# How can I find all rows that have at least one element in an array matching a pattern?

Tags: postgresql, array

Consider the following example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE testing (
    names TEXT[]
);

INSERT INTO testing VALUES
    ('{toplevel1}'),
    ('{toplevel1.sub1, toplevel2.sub2}'),
    ('{toplevel1.sub1.sub2, toplevel2.sub2}'),
    ('{toplevel1.sub1.sub3, toplevel2.sub2}'),
    ('{toplevel1.sub1.sub3.sub3, toplevel2.sub2}'),
    ('{toplevel2.sub1}')
;

SELECT * FROM testing WHERE 'toplevel1.%' ILIKE ANY(names);
```

I want to write a select where "any" element of an array matches a pattern. But I can't figure out a way to do it. In the example I've given, using the `ILIKE` operator can't work because it checks if the RHS matches the LHS. For this case I would need a similar operator but which checks if the LHS matches the RHS.

*update:* I'm currently fiddling around with something like this without much success:

```
SELECT * FROM testing WHERE names ILIKE ANY (ARRAY(SELECT unnest(names) || '%'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official [ltree](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html) extension.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS ltree;

CREATE TEMP TABLE testing (
    names ltree[]
);

INSERT INTO testing (names)
VALUES
    ('{toplevel1}'),
    ('{toplevel1.sub1, toplevel2.sub2}'),
    ('{toplevel1.sub1.sub2, toplevel2.sub2}'),
    ('{toplevel1.sub1.sub3, toplevel2.sub2}'),
    ('{toplevel1.sub1.sub3.sub3, toplevel2.sub2}'),
    ('{toplevel2.sub1}');

SELECT * FROM testing WHERE names ~ 'toplevel1.*';
```

It is also doable in "plain" postgresql:

```
SELECT * FROM testing AS t
WHERE (
    SELECT true 
    FROM unnest(t.names) AS n
    WHERE n ILIKE 'toplevel1.%'
    LIMIT 1
);
```

The ltree extension is not very widely used, and obviously it has some limitations (including label length & character set), but it's stable and can achieve better performance than unnest-based version. I would really give it a try.

Comment: For the example I have given, this is indeed a good solution. Unfortunately I am working on a DB where I would like to avoid adding an extension as it's from a 3rd party and not 100% in our control. I'm currently only adding views.

Comment: @exhuma ok. so make friends with `unnest` :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a *fairly* similar solution with pure SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM testing WHERE true = ANY (ARRAY(SELECT unnest(names) ILIKE 'toplevel1%'));
```

This applies the `ILIKE` operator first over all array elements, yielding an array with only `true`/`false` values. This is then trivial to compare using the `ANY` operator.